# Run this on the notes of every slide of my PowerPoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint, desktop-publishing

I am trying to get this code to run on the Notes of every slide of a long PPT presentation. It changes the Latin font to Calibri and Asian (in my case, Chinese) font to MS YaHei.

How can I change this code for it to work on every page and not just the selection, like in my case?

```
Sub YahEmb()
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font

.NameAscii = "Calibri"
.NameFarEast = "Microsoft YaHei"
.NameOther = "Calibri"

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the presentation is well-constructed, all you have to do is set a new font theme. If it's not well-constructed, updating the Notes Master will do the same thing. No code required.